# Reducing DB size while restoring

Tags: sql-server-2008, restore

I have DB backup with size approx. 150 Mb.

I am trying to restore it and getting an error:
"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: There is insufficient free space on disk volume 'C:\' to create the database. The database requires 67771760640 additional free bytes, while only 45085224960 bytes are available. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)"

Restore is about to create DB with much bigger size than backup has. Is there a possibility to reduce size of DB being restored?

Comment: If the backup was compressed, then your actual database may be 67 GB...

Comment: @JNK, can I somehow find out it backup was compressed?

Comment: Use [`RESTORE HEADERONLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178536.aspx) -- there is a column `Compressed` that will be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A restore always restores the files to the same sizes they were when they were backed up.

There is currently no way to "restore with shrink."

You'll need to restore the files to a drive with sufficient free space, and perhaps consider shrinking the files at that point, then use your preferred technique to move the files to the spot you want.

Comment: Alter database + set offline + move files manually + set online is much, much safer than detach + move + attach.